# Authenticate via Windows AD integration without login popup

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, windows-authentication

I have disabled anonymous access. My pool is using "Integrated Windows Authentication".

Problem: 
When a logged in user in Windows (logged in user entry is there in AD) tries to access my application in browser, a windows authentication login box appears in the browser.

Can we avoid that? Since the user has already logged into the machine can't we make some setting to allow browsers to use the same credentials instead of prompting the login modal.

In research of that I went to this link too [How to automatically authenticate windows integrate without login popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762700/how-to-automatically-authenticate-windows-integrate-without-login-popup) where I saw the solution for IE only which can be done via:

"go to Tools -> Internet Option -> Security -> Custom Level -> Scroll the whole way to the bottom and select "Automatic Login with current user name and password” -> OK -> OK -> Close and reopen browser."

This means I have to go to each user machine and set that setting in their IE browser. Can't we do via IIS or web.config of the application?

Also, this solution was for IE only, what about others? like Chrome and FF. How can we prevent the login prompt in Chrome and FF?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox uses a setting in about:config to define a "whitelist" for using windows auth.

```
network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris
```

Basically you just put in the server names separated by commas.

Chrome just uses the "Local Intranet" sites list defined in Windows (Same as what IE uses)