# Authenticate From windows login in our website

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, active-directory

I want to authenticate in my web site from windows username and without a login form but our active directory of our users is in another server?How can I do it? How can I create a connection between these two servers?
I work with C# and ASP.net 
Please answer me as soon as possible
I have a short deadline to do it!
with the Best regards

Comment: Your question will be answered better, if you improve your tags.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is, that your web-server must be in the same domain as the active-directory server. 
Than you have to add `<authentication mode="Windows"/>` in your webconfig, so that the IIS know, you want to use window authentication. You have to place this tag in the `<system.web>`-Tag.

The last thing you have to do is described here: [How to automatically authenticate windows integrate without login popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4762813/2630261)

Here is a complete article from the MSDN: [How To: Use Windows Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx)